# EOFError: Ran out of input errror when I load a pickle file having dictionary object

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to save and load dictionary variables made by multiprocessing.manger.

```
with Manager() as manager:
    score = manager.dict()
    entropy = manager.dict()
    score['a'] = 1
    score['b'] = 2
    f_score = open("tttttttt.pkl", "wb")
    pickle.dump(dict(score), f_score)
with open('tttttttt.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    score_dic = pickle.load(f)
```

But, I got this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ukjo/anaconda3/envs/spyder/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-ccd52887eacf>", line 2, in <module>
    score_dic = pickle.load(f)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: Did the answer I posted resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You carefully used a `with` context handler to make sure your input file, `f`, would be closed, where it really wasn't that essential for an input file (although certainly the proper thing to do to free up resources), but neglected to do this for the pickle output file where it was absolutely essential to close the file to ensure that all the data is flushed out.

Change your code accordingly:

```
with open("tttttttt.pkl", "wb") as f_score:
    pickle.dump(dict(score), f_score)
```